# How to create another Column in Qlikview

Tags: arrays, loading, qlikview

I would like to speed up calculations in application by putting it on script level.

I need to create another column with a calculation so it will speed up my application.

So here is the data:

**Table 1 - Cars**

Model       S/N         Delivery

```
A   111 10/10/2015
B   222 10/10/2015
A   112 11/10/2015
C   333 13/10/2015
```

**Table 2 - Maintenance**

Model   Timeframe (Days)      MO      Type of maintenance   US$

```
A   10  6   XXX  100
A   10  6   yyy  150
A   15  7   ZZZ  200
B   10  6   XXX  100
B   10  6   yyy  150
C   30  9   AbAb 200
```

I would like to sum "Delivery" with "Timeframe" and name it as "date of maintenance" and put in Table 3.

Here is my desired Table:

**Table 3:**

Model   S/N Delivery    Date of Maintenance MO  Type of Maintenance US$

```
A   111 10/10/2015  20/10/2015  6   XXX 100
A   111 10/10/2015  20/10/2015 6    yyy 150
A   111 10/10/2015  25/10/2015  7   ZZZ 200
B   222 10/10/2015  20/10/2015  6   XXX 100
B   222 10/10/2015  20/10/2015  6   yyy 150
A   112 11/10/2015  21/10/2015  6   XXX 100
A   112 11/10/2015  21/10/2015  6   yyy 150
A   112 11/10/2015  26/10/2015  7   ZZZ 200
C   333 13/10/2015  12/11/2015  9   AbAb    200
```

I will appreciate If someone can help me. I just though of creating another table because it will simplify the view, but if you have an easier way it would be great.

Comment: Unclear. What is "by putting it on script level" ? Could you edit your question and explain what you have tried already (post some code ?).

Comment: Hi Kebs, Sorry for being unclear.
I am new to Qlikview. "by putting it on script level" means doing the calculations on the script instead of doing in the charts.

Actually I got stucked at this point and have no code to perform this action yet.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry, everybody's here to help, but the point is to maintain question quality so they can be useful to others, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. You can always edit your question to improve it afterwards (click on 'edit' at the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Either join the tables, or bring in only the field that you want by way of a mapping.

https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2015/03/27/mapping-as-an-alternative-to-joining

Comment: Hi, I had used mapping but it doesn't work. Maybe its because the table Car is "n" and table maintenance is "1". When I did mapping, it just show me the first value. Like you take the first row from table one and from table 2, leaving the rows 2 and 3 from table 2.

Comment: Load the Cars table first as some temporary name...say "tmpCars", then left-join the Maintenance table to "tmpCars". Once joined, do one final resident load into a new table called "Cars" where you'll add the timeframe to the delivery date to come up with your new column. When complete, drop "tmpCars". https://community.qlik.com/message/683394#683394